# Database/collections arbitrary but specific order

Tags: mongodb, collections, database

I want to create a database (I'm using mongodb) collection that has a specific order which can also be rearranged.  For example, if I have

```
[A,B,C,D,E]
```

I could move E to the third position, and the order would be

```
[A,B,E,C,D]
```

I would like to change as few objects as possible, so putting an index on each object would not work (since I'd need to change all subsequent elements' indexes for a simple move).

I could also create the objects like a linked list, so each object would have the id of the previous and next objects.  The example change would go like this.

```
["A":{prev:null, next:"B"},
"B":{prev:"A", next:"C"},
"C":{prev:"B", next:"D"},
"D":{prev:"C", next:"E"},
"E":{prev:"D", next:null}]
```

would change to

```
["A":{prev:null, next:"B"},
"B":{prev:"A", next:"E"},
"C":{prev:"E", next:"D"},
"D":{prev:"C", next:null},
"E":{prev:"B", next:"C"}]
```

This changes at most 5 objects for any size collection.  A change can be expressed as one updated object, with some logic to figure out what other objects need to be updated.  This is doable, but I was wondering if there was a better way than this even.  Is there an easier way to keep track of the order of an arbitrary list?

Comment: How are you querying this collection? Is it always the whole list, or are you trying to pull a subset range? Also, does this need to be scalable to really big numbers of lists?

Comment: Yes, it will be querying the whole list.  I imagine the list will grow to ~500 objects.

Comment: Interesting problem. I'm curious what the performance will be with only 500. It probably doesn't matter whether you do it this way or with a simple order value. Your linked list method will need to run 3 queries and 3 distinct updates, where the order value will need to run one query and one multi-value update (worst-case needs to update all but one doc) I'll try some benchmarks.

Comment: What would the multi-value update syntax look like?  I was originally thinking I'd have to individually update each object.

Comment: I'm about to post my code. Looks like your method is a bit faster for updates, but querying it in order might be more painful (but you could do it on the client pretty quickly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, your linked list way is quite a bit faster and more scalable than the multi-update method, but with collection size at 500, I get about 7ms per "move" (with my benchmark code--obviously different sized collections might make a difference). Further, if you want to be able to order the collection on the server, having an "order" value to index/sort on will make it a lot easier. As the collection size increases, the multi-update method increases accordingly on average, which makes sense, as it's roughly O(n). Your method stays pretty consistent at 0.8ms per move, regardless of size, which also makes sense, as it's O(1).

Here is my populate code for the two tests, which illustrates the simple schema design/index config:

```
var populateMulti = function(colSize) {
   db.test10.drop();
   for(var i=0;i<colSize;i++) {
      db.test10.save({name:""+i, order:i});
   }  
   db.test10.ensureIndex({order:1});
}

var populateLinked = function(colSize) {
   db.test10.drop();
   db.test10.save({name: ""+0, prev:null, next:""+1});
   for(var i=1;i<colSize-1;i++) {
      db.test10.save({name:""+i, prev:""+(i-1), next:""+(i+1)});
   }  
   db.test10.save({name: ""+(colSize-1), prev:""+(i-1), next:null});
   db.test10.ensureIndex({name:1});
}
```

Here's my move code for both. You were right about the potential 5 updates--I hadn't thought it all the way through.

```
var moveMulti = function(oldPos,newPos) {
   if(oldPos == newPos) return;
   db.test10.update({order:oldPos}, 
                    {$set:{order:newPos, hold:true}}, 
                    false, false);
   if(oldPos < newPos) {
      db.test10.update({order:{$gt:oldPos, $lte:newPos}, hold:{$exists:false}},
                       {$inc:{order:-1}}, 
                       false, true);
   } else if(newPos < oldPos) {
      db.test10.update({order:{$gte:newPos, $lt:oldPos}, hold:{$exists:false}},
                       {$inc:{order:1}}, 
                       false, true);
   }
   db.test10.update({order:newPos}, 
                    {$unset:{hold:1}}, 
                    false, false);
}

var moveLinked = function(oldPos,newPos) {
   var toMove = db.test10.findOne({name:""+oldPos});
   var dest = db.test10.findOne({name:""+newPos});
   if(toMove.prev != null) {
      db.test10.update({name: toMove.prev}, {$set:{next:toMove.next}}, false, false);
   }
   if(toMove.next != null) {
      db.test10.update({name: toMove.next}, {$set:{prev:toMove.prev}}, false, false);
   }
   if(dest.prev != null) {
      db.test10.update({name: dest.prev}, {$set:{next:toMove.name}}, false, false);
   }
   db.test10.update({name: toMove.name}, {$set:{prev:dest.prev, next:dest.name}}, false, false);
   db.test10.update({name: dest.name}, {$set:{prev:toMove.name}}, false, false);
}
```

I'll omit the benchmark code. See the whole thing here if you want to run it yourself:
https://gist.github.com/1700270

Here are the results on my laptop:

```
coll size: 10; finished 5000 moves with multi-update in: 1188ms; 0.2376ms per move
coll size: 10; finished 5000 moves with linked in: 3593ms; 0.7186ms per move
coll size: 100; finished 5000 moves with multi-update in: 7545ms; 1.509ms per move
coll size: 100; finished 5000 moves with linked in: 3800ms; 0.76ms per move
coll size: 500; finished 5000 moves with multi-update in: 37754ms; 7.5508ms per move
coll size: 500; finished 5000 moves with linked in: 4027ms; 0.8054ms per move
coll size: 1000; finished 5000 moves with multi-update in: 71609ms; 14.3218ms per move
coll size: 1000; finished 5000 moves with linked in: 4221ms; 0.8442ms per move
coll size: 10000; finished 5000 moves with multi-update in: 676043ms; 135.2086ms per move
coll size: 10000; finished 5000 moves with linked in: 4041ms; 0.8082ms per move
```

Comment: FYI, the multi-update flag is the 4th parameter for update, so if you set that to true it will update all of the matching docs.

Comment: I had a bug in moveMulti when old and new are the same. Doesn't change the benchmarks, though.

Comment: Excellent work!  This is very revealing.  I imagine that sorting the data on the server isn't too important, because it will all be processed by the client.  If I were to sort the linked list on the server, it would also make the work O(n).

Comment: How much data (total size), would you say your 500 elements make up. If it's small enough, you might be able to get away with just storing it in one document, pulling it out, updating the array, and then saving it. Arrays within documents keep their order.